# Reading through a File with a Buffered Reader

Tags: java, xml, stax, woodstox

**Background**

I am writing a xml converter that takes input from textfiles and translates them to xml. In the text file each record is represented by a line and each field is represented with a tab between them. So in the text file two records would look like:

```
fieldA     fieldB     fieldC
fieldA     fieldB     fieldC
```

**Problem**

I am loading the text file into a bufferedReader and using the StAX implementation WoodStox to create the XML. I can see that I am getting the correct record data from my getColumnValue method. But for some reason WoodStox is writing the first record over and over, rather than taking the data that is being delivered each time through the while loop. Since I know inputs (from getColumnValue) are coming in correct, I can only conclude that the problem lies with Woodstock but so far I haven't been able to understand why...

Code:

```
while ((strRead = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

    String recordInputs[] = strRead.split("\t");
    writer.writeStartElement("Record");

    writer.writeStartElement("FIELDA");
    writer.writeCharacters(getColumnValue("BSTYPE", tableColumns, recordInputs));
    writer.writeEndElement();

    writer.writeStartElement("FIELDB");
    writer.writeCharacters(getColumnValue("BSDDT", tableColumns, recordInputs));
    writer.writeEndElement();

    writer.writeStartElement("FIELDC");
    writer.writeCharacters(getColumnValue("BSACTIVE", tableColumns, recordInputs));
    writer.writeEndElement();

    writer.writeEndElement();
}

writer.writeEndElement();
writer.writeEndDocument();

writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: No idea what `getColumnValue()` does, but why not just do `writer.writeCharacters(recordInputs[0])`?

Comment: getColumnValue() is returning a string. It returns the correct string for each iteration of the while loop. So I know that getColumnValue() isn't where the problem is.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem with the code you've posted, so you should include the code for your `getColumnValue` method.  I agree with @Andreas that it's unclear what value that method could have, when you can simply access the elements of your `recordInputs` array directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a good answer to why this didn't work but I did manage to fix it.

Non Working:

```
writer.writeCharacters(getColumnValue("BSTYPE", tableColumns, customer));
```

Working:

```
String bsType = getColumnValue("BSTYPE", tableColumns, customer);
writer.writeCharacters(csType);
```

Like I previously said getColumnValue() returns a string so I have no idea why that change fixes the problem, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here it is:

```java
String input = "1\t2\t3\r\n" +
               "4\t5\t6\r\n";
XMLStreamWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
System.out.println(writer.getClass());
writer.writeStartDocument();
writer.writeStartElement("Root");
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input))) {
    for (String strRead; (strRead = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        String recordInputs[] = strRead.split("\t");
        writer.writeStartElement("Record");

        writer.writeStartElement("FIELDA");
        writer.writeCharacters(recordInputs[0]);
        writer.writeEndElement();

        writer.writeStartElement("FIELDB");
        writer.writeCharacters(recordInputs[1]);
        writer.writeEndElement();

        writer.writeStartElement("FIELDC");
        writer.writeCharacters(recordInputs[2]);
        writer.writeEndElement();

        writer.writeEndElement();
    }
}
writer.writeEndElement();
writer.writeEndDocument();
writer.flush(); // Don't close System.out
```

When run on Java 8 *without* Woodstox, I get (formatted for readability):

```xml
class com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Root>
    <Record><FIELDA>1</FIELDA><FIELDB>2</FIELDB><FIELDC>3</FIELDC></Record>
    <Record><FIELDA>4</FIELDA><FIELDB>5</FIELDB><FIELDC>6</FIELDC></Record>
</Root>
```

As you can see, it's using the built-in Java implementation, and values are good.

When run with `woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar` and `stax2-api-3.1.1.jar` on the classpath, I get (formatted for readability):

```xml
class com.ctc.wstx.sw.SimpleNsStreamWriter

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Root>
    <Record><FIELDA>1</FIELDA><FIELDB>2</FIELDB><FIELDC>3</FIELDC></Record>
    <Record><FIELDA>4</FIELDA><FIELDB>5</FIELDB><FIELDC>6</FIELDC></Record>
</Root>
```

As you can see, it's using the Woodstox implementation, and values are still good.

**Since you didn't include the logic of `getColumnValue()`, or a verifiable example, or the version of Woodstox you're using, there nothing else we can do to help you.**

Comment: Thanks for trying but see my answer below or my initial question for why I didn't include getColumnValue()...